# JavaScript JS Class Method for changing property value sent as parameter from another method

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods, reference

What I know so far for JavaScript is that parameters passed to a function are passed by value, but the values itself are references. Let's look at the following example:

```
function change(obj){
    obj.x = 10;
}

var myObj = {x: 5};
console.log(myObj);    //Object {x: 5}

change(myObj);
console.log(myObj);    //Object {x: 10}
```

Let's say we have the following class:

```
var myClass = (function(){
    function myClass(){
         this.x = 5;
    }

    myClass.prototype.changeX = function(val){
         this.x = val;
    }

    return myClass;
})();

var myObj = new myClass();
console.log(myObj);    //myClass {x: 5}

myObj.changeX(10);
console.log(myObj);    //myClass {x: 10}
```

Everything looks okay so far. And let's extend our class:

```
var myClass = (function(){
    function myClass(){
         this.x = 5;
    }

    myClass.prototype.changeX = function(prop, val){
         prop = val;
    }

    myClass.prototype.changer = function(){
         this.changeX(this.x, 10);
    }

    return myClass;
})();

var myObj = new myClass();
console.log(myObj);    //myClass {x: 5}

myObj.changer();
console.log(myObj);    //myClass {x: 5}
```

So why in the latest example the `myObj`'s `x` property is not changed? How can I modify the latest example's `changer` method so that it calls `changeX` method by sending `this.x` and value to be assigned to it as a parameter?

Comment: That `prop` becomes a representation of the variable in the context of the function. It's not actually set to `this.x`, you're just passing the value of `this.x` by reference. Primitives are passed by value, while Objects are passed by "copy of a reference". This is a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing in a primitive type, like a number/string, the value is passed in by value, but when you're passing in an object/array/function, it is by reference. You were passing in the object's property, not the object itself.

```
var myClass = (function(){
    function myClass(){
         this.x = 5;
    }

    myClass.prototype.changeX = function(prop, val){
         prop.x = val;
    }

    myClass.prototype.changer = function(){
         this.changeX(this, 10); //Pass the object, not the object property
    }

    return myClass;
})();

var myObj = new myClass();
console.log(myObj);    //myClass {x: 5}

myObj.changer();
console.log(myObj);    //myClass {x: 10}
```

**By value:**

- null
- undefined
- string
- number
- boolean

**By reference:**

- object
- array
- function

Comment: Now that makes sense. Thank you!